# AJV Standalone validation code from typescript files

Tags: typescript, ajv

I did some schemas using JSONSchemaType in some .ts file following the [documentation](https://ajv.js.org/guide/typescript.html).
It does work when compiling during initialization, but I would like to generate the standalone validation code to keep `unsafe-eval` in my Content Security Policies.
The [ajv-cli](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv-cli) needs json files to do so, is there a simple way I could keep my type safeties on my schemas declared in .ts file and still generate the validation code ?